# sort csv file using unix utililty sort

Tags: sorting, csv

is there a way to sort very large CSV file using `sort`?
Simply sort by the first column, however, the data might contain line breaks within a column (standard CSV file rules apply).  Would the line breaks break the `sort` utility?

Comment: Actually quite difficult. You might want to take a look at my FOSS project at http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/ which does sorting of CSV files, among many other things, and runs on Unix.

Comment: @Neil Bufferworth: cool! would it work for large csv files with line breaks within column data?

Comment: and what is the performance of csvfix on 10 millions of rows?

Comment: @user Not too good I'd guess, the sort is performed in memory. I haven't tested it on enormous inputs.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: if it only sort in memory and no merge sort from disk, then it won't work for large inputs, right?

Comment: @user Correct - it's primarily designed to meet meet my own needs, which are for processing files containing a few thousand records. The next version will have a merge command, which may meet your requirements, but it won't be available for a while yet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try something like this `cat old.csv | sort > new.csv`

UPD: To prepare data if needed we can use AWK script....

Comment: read the question properly. _"the data might contain line breaks"_

Comment: It's quite simple to prepare data using a AWK script, which is exactly for preparing (formating) huge log files)) I didn't say that this command would work, I sad smth like this...

Answer (score 0):

The sort function will sort the lines in asciicographical order.  To get a more sophisticated effect, you might use the UNIX utility awk.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a mix of utilities. Hopefully I've understood it correctly ... and if so, this might do the job. IF not, point out where I've gone wrong in an assumption :-) This requires that the number of fields per CSV record is fixed (it's also a dirt simple example that doesn't cover various CSV variations (e.g., hello,"world,how",are,you would break as "world,how" would be split into two fields)):

```
hello,world,how,are,you
one,two,three,four,five
once,I,caught,a
fish,alive
hey,now,hey,now,now
```

And this awk script:

```
BEGIN {
        FS=","
        fields=0
}

{
        if (line == "") {
                fields=NF
                line = $0
        } else {
                fields=fields + (NF - 1)
                line=line"|"$0
        }
}

fields == 5 {
        print line
        fields = 0
        line = ""
}
```

Executing this:

```
awk -f join.awk < infile | sort | tr '|' '\n'
```

gives this output:

```
hello,world,how,are,you
hey,now,hey,now,now
once,I,caught,a
fish,alive
one,two,three,four,five
```

In essence, all we're doing with the awk script is merging the multi-line records into a single-line that we can then feed to `sort`, then break again with `tr`. I'm using a pipe as the replacement for the newline char -- just choose something that you can gurantee will not appear in a CSV record.

Now it might not be perfect for what you want, but hopefully it'll nudge you in the right direction. The main thing with the awk script I've knocked up is that it needs to know how many fields there are per CSV record. This needs to be fixed. If it's variable, then all bets are off as there'd need to be more rules in there do define the semantic nature of the file that you want to sort...

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is to temporarily modify your data so that the standard UNIX sort command can properly interpret your data.

You can use a program called csvquote which replaces the problematic commas and newlines inside quoted field values with nonprinting characters. Then it restores those characters at the end of your pipeline.

For example,

```
csvquote inputfile.csv | sort | csvquote -u
```

You can find the code here: https://github.com/dbro/csvquote